# Jackknife syntax for SPSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spss

I am trying to construct syntax in SPSS to perform a "leave-one-out" analysis (aka jackknife) where I systematically remove one case at a time, then run an analysis (e.g. GLM or PCA) on each iteration to identify specific cases that might contribute to large amounts of variance in the dataset.

Comment: Stackoverflow question needs more details and what's recommended is to provide working codes. Consider posting this question with it for people to find out your problem and help you out with more ease.

Comment: I don't have working codes.  Been doing everything manually.  I am trying to find some examples of SPSS syntax that can select cases in a data file based on some conditional criteria (e.g. SubjectID = N-1, then N-2, then N-3, etc), to systematically exclude a different case prior to running different statistical tests, such as a general linear model or a factor analysis, and then to compile all the results into a summary table of descriptive statistics for each iteration to test for wobble in the results that may be due to one or more specific cases being dropped from the analysis.